# Error en getApplicationContext() Android

Tags: android, layout, android-context

Estoy tratando de cargar un `Toast` Messagge. Dentro de una clase que "pinta"
un `ViewPager`. El problema es que estoy teniendo un error a la hora de recoger el contexto. Que podría estar haciendo mal?

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){...}
    public void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Button btnTick = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonInvertirTick);
    btnTick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    }
}
```

No he copiado todo el código ya que se quedaría algo extenso el post y el error es el siguiente **Cannot resolve´getApplicationContext()´**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reemplaza `getApplicationContext()` por `getActivity()`.

Si vas a trabajar con mas elementos que necesiten del `Context` te aconsejo que en tu `Fragment` inicialices :

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, text, duration);
```

EDICION

> getActivity()
>   Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

Tal como dice la documentación el metodo `getActivity()` trae la `activity` (El contexto) a la cual esta asociado a tu `Fragment`

> getApplicationContext()
>   Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process.

Te dejo mas [info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) de la documentacion oficial.

Comment: funciono perfectamente, pero a que se debe ese cambio??

Comment: @EduardoMéndez actualice mi respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Como complemento a esta pregunta debes recordar que **si te encuentras en un `Fragment` usa `getActivity()` para obtener el contexto**, (ya que un `Fragment` siempre esta contenido en una Activity).

```
   Context context = getActivity();
```

En el caso de estar en una Activity puedes usar `this` para hacer referencia a la `Activity` o usar `getApplicationContext()` para obtener el contexto de la aplicación.

```
  Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

---

Tu código corregido sería:

```
  public void onClick (View v) {
            Context context = getActivity(); //*** Aquí el cambio.
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;    
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Comment: espero tu +1 jajaja estoy aprendiendo ya de los Fragment :D!

Comment: Claro, por cierto si hiciste la prueba de reutilizar el fragment en varias Activity?

Comment: aun no :(, estoy con harto trabajo y no he tenido mucho tiempo, supiste algo de tu WebCast? para estar atento y verlo

Comment: ah eso es mediante invitación de Juan.